# C# - What should I do with empty if-brackets?

Tags: c#

I've ended up with some pretty ugly code while doing some bitmasking:

```
    if (BitmaskIntersection(north, south, west, east)) { } //Logic is executed inside these methods, and return true or false. 
    else if (BitmaskTCross(north, south, west, east)) { }
    else if (BitmaskStraightBend(north, south, west, east)) { }
    else if (BitmaskEnd(north, south, west, east)) { }
    else
    {
        meshFilter.mesh = single;
    }

    ExecuteOnceAnIfReturnsTrue();
}
```

As you can see I've ended up with several empty brackets here. The code works since I always bitmask the highest number of neighbors first, but it feels ugly. Can it be improved? How should this be handled?

Comment: This question is incomplete. To help reviewers give you better answers, please add sufficient context to your question. The more you tell us about what your code does and what the purpose of doing that is, the easier it will be for reviewers to help you. [Questions should include a description of what the code does](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1231/42632).

Comment: The site standard is for the title to simply state the task accomplished by the code, not your concers about it. Please see [How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) for examples, and revise the title accordingly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just put everything in the same if using "or"

```
if (!(BitmaskIntersection(north, south, west, east) || 
    BitmaskTCross(north, south, west, east) ||
    BitmaskStraightBend(north, south, west, east) ||
    BitmaskEnd(north, south, west, east)))    
{
    meshFilter.mesh = single;
}
```

In C#, "or" are short-circuited, which means it stops when it reaches the first `true` statement

or use "and":

```
if (!BitmaskIntersection(north, south, west, east) &&
    !BitmaskTCross(north, south, west, east) &&
    !BitmaskStraightBend(north, south, west, east) &&
    !BitmaskEnd(north, south, west, east))    
{
    meshFilter.mesh = single;
}
```

In C#, "and" are also short-circuited, which means it stops when it reaches the first `false` statement